# Call Bibtex files for citation in PowerPoint?

Tags: bibtex, powerpoint

Is it possible to call Bibtex files for citation in MS PowerPoint. Is there any such add-in or software to do this?

Comment: It's time to try `Beamer`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_%28LaTeX%29

Comment: I am already using Beamer but being able to create bibliography using Bibtex file in PowerPoint would make my life much easier. I want to use PowerPoint because I will have more control over the pictures (resizing, locating,...etc) which I found to be sometimes very annoying and time consuming in Beamer. But, I also want to include all of the references I am using as a footnote in each slide in PowerPoint.

Comment: AFAIK There is none. :(

Comment: [Bibtex4Word](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/perl/) add-in for Microsoft Word allows the citation of references and the insertion of a bibliography into your word document `.doc`, I have no idea if it can be extended to `.ppt/x` files.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know is there no possibility to call BiBTeX in PowerPoint.

What you can try is to use a program like [citavi](http://citavi.com/en/index.html) or perhaps Menderly or ... If these programs are able to import a bibtex file you can use them to integrate your citations into Powerpoint.  As far as I know you can use Citavi in PowerPoint.